# jquery toggle not working with infinite scroll and masonry

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

Basic setup is a series of divs that have additional info that slides down when a link is clicked. Works great for the first page of items, but any additional items display with the hidden div showing and the toggle link js doesn't work.

```
$(".hidden_info").hide();
$(".toggle_link").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest(".item").find(".hidden_info").slideToggle("slow");
});

var $container = $('#content');

$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.item'
  });
});

$container.infinitescroll({
navSelector  : "div.navigation",
nextSelector : "div.navigation a:first",
itemSelector : "#content div.item",
    loading: {
                        msgText  : "Loading new products...",
              finishedMsg: 'No more products to load.',
            }
},
function( newElements ) {
var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
$newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
  $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
});
});
```

-edit-
Ok I have the toggle aspect working using the .on method. New code looks like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".toggle_link", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest(".item").find(".hidden_info").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

But the .hide stuff isn't working right. I may just end up switching what gets hidden so the content positioned above shows by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So switching around what's absolutely and relatively positioned wasn't a good option due to the dynamic heights of the elements. So I went with putting an inline style of display: none on the hidden divs. Not my favorite choice due to accessibility for people not using javascript. But it works.